# Hypothesized a theorem regarding limsups with non convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I was working on a [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtsjl.png)(picture) and it got me wondering about the cases in which the equality doesn't hold. It got me to come up with a theorem. I'd like to know if this is true (I think it is) and a proof would be nice(working on one, but not complete yet) I basically defined K_S and K_T to be "indices" in which the respective limsups appear.

$Theorem:Let\ S_n\ and\ T_n\ be\ both\ bounded\ but\ both\ non convergent\ sequences. 
\\Let\ K_S := \{n|n\in\mathbb{N}\ and\ S_n = lim sup (S_n)\}
\\Let\ K_T := \{n|n\in\mathbb{N}\ and\ T_n = lim sup (T_n)\}
\\If K_S \cap K_T = \varnothing\ ,\ then\
\\lim sup (S_n+T_n) <  lim sup (S_n)+lim sup (T_n)$

Comment: The definitions of $K_S$ and $K_T$ are unreadable, at least to me. Be as it may, compare with $S_n=(-1)^n(1-2^{-n})$, $T_n=5+(-1)^n(1-2^{-n})$, for which $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} S_n+T_n=7=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} S_n+ \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}T_n$.

Comment: It would help with human readability to include all appropriate quantifiers, correctly placed (i.e. at the beginning, just after the "such that" symbol) and correctly ordered (if more than one).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I just made some changes to my definition of $K_S$ and $K_T$. From my understanding, your counter example wouldn't count because the intersection of $K_S$ and $K_T$ is not empty. The lim sups for each sequences will appear at the same value of n's (if that makes sense).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro would the changes in the definition now make sense? Sorry, for the confusion I'm still developing my mathematical writing abilities.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what $K_S, K_T$ are but you require $S_n=\limsup S_n$, which never happens for the sequences given above.

Comment: Also avoid using "for any" in mathematical writing, since it is ambiguous. Instead use "for all" or "there exists".

Comment: You're using the symbol $n$ in what appears to be both as a [bound variable and a free variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables), which is confusing -- makes it difficult to tell whether what you have written is what you actually intend. Also, you have written the symbol $N$ prior to saying anything about $N.$ It's a little clearer to have "for all $N \in \mathbb R$" before you use $N$ in a relation.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your idea but here is the thing. You have bounded sequences, hence by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem we have that there exists an increasing subsequence of $T_n$ which converges to the $limsupT_n$. Same for $S_n$. So even if these set have an empty intersection, what you get at best is the well known inequality $$\limsup(a_n+b_n)\leq \limsup a_n+\limsup b_n.$$

I want to note though that your effort and your energy put into your proof will not be fruitless just because you did not prove something new. You are doing fine, and these little efforts will improve you. This is what mathematics are for.